# take a photo to pc since a application c#?

Tags: c#, directory, savefiledialog

I want to print all the screen with a button, and save it in any folder ( i know how to do it ) but i dont know how to take the photo ... and another thing, I want this program is HIDE and it works with a key for example f9 or f11 or any key, but i want this continue HIDE and working, how to take the print pant? and how to work if it is hide?

thanks stackoverflow and partherns

Comment: I applaud your ability to create a language that looks so similar to English.

Comment: Your English is too mangled for me to be able to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below method to take the screenshot of a single window or the whole screen:

```
    public void WindowsScreenshot()
    {
        // Full
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save("test_full.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        // Window
        Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save("test_window.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```